# Monotony of $x\cot(x)$ in an interval

Tags: calculus, functions, trigonometry

Once again, I find myself struggling to show something which I believe is very simple.

Given a function
$f(x)=x \cot(x)$, I want to show that $f$ is monotonic-decreasing in the interval $(0,\frac{\pi}{2})$.

My first approach would be to take $x_1, x_2 \in (0,\frac{\pi}{2}), \ x_1 < x_2$ and show $f(x_2) - f(x_1) < 0$:

$$\begin{align}
& f(x_2)-f(x_1) = x_2\cdot \cot(x_2) - x_1\cdot \cot(x_1) < 0 \\
& \Leftrightarrow x_2\cdot \cot(x_2) < x_1\cdot \cot(x_1) \\
& \Leftrightarrow \frac{x_2}{x_1} < \frac{\cot(x_1)}{\cot(x_2)}
\end{align}$$

At which point I don't know how to continue. Intuitively, it is clear to me that the last inequality is true, since the rate of change in $cot$ is 'much higher' than that in $x$. But how would I write that out soundly?

The second approach would be to show that $f'(x)<0$ for $x \in (0,\frac{\pi}{2})$:
$$
f'(x) = \cot(x) - \frac{x}{\sin^2(x)}
$$
But how would I show that that's below zero in the specified interval?

Anyway, I feel like I have spent way too much time trying to figure out something simple which I should 'just see'. I tried using the derivative of $cot$ in the first approach, and trigonometric identities in both, but I guess I just don't see it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**:
With the second approach, rewrite the derivative as
$$f'(x)=\frac{\cos x}{\sin x}-\frac{x}{\sin^2 x}=\frac{\sin 2x -2x}{2\sin^2x}$$
and use that the function $\sin 2x$ is concave on $\bigl[0,\frac\pi 2\bigr]$, hence its graph is below  each of its  tangents on this interval.

Comment: +1. I think there is a typo, it should be $f'(x)=\frac{\cos x}{\sin x} -\frac{x}{\sin^2 x}$.

Comment: Right – some copy-paste problem. One should always reread before posting! I've fixed it. Thank you so much for pointing it!

Comment: @Bernard That's it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I like to look at the reciprocal and prove it is increasing.

The reciprocal is $\tan x /x$. As the Taylor series for $\tan x$ has only odd powers, dividing by $x$ makes no difference, and it's enough to show that the coefficients of the Taylor series for $\tan x$ are non-negative.

We all ought to know that the coefficients of the function $\tan x$ have a combinatorial interpretation; see [Up-down permutations.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_permutation) They are natural numbers divided by a factorial, and so they are all non-negative.

I realise that this is probably - maybe certainly - not the sort of proof you are looking for, but it has its interest.